# Run java applet offline: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I just downloaded some java applets from this site: http://www.surendranath.org/Apps.html to run them offline on my laptop. Take for example this one: http://www.surendranath.org/Applets/Oscillations/Lissajous/Lissajous.html

By inspecting the source code I downloaded the file:  `wget http://www.surendranath.org/Applets/Oscillations/Lissajous/LissajousApplet.class`

Then I tried it to run it on my ubuntu box via `gappletviewer-4.8 -code LissayousApplet.class`

However I got the following error message:

```
Exception in thfully qualifiedread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: loaded class LissajousApplet was in fact named Applets.Oscillations.Lissajous.LissajousApplet
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.Main.createApplet(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.StandaloneAppletWindow.<init>(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.StandaloneAppletViewer.createWindows(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.StandaloneAppletViewer.<init>(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.Main.main(libgcj-tools.so.14)
```

So what is the correct way to run this applet **offline**? Running it online within my browser and the icetea plugin works. However I need a way to run it offline.

**Edit**

Trying the fully qualified class-name results in:

```
gappletviewer-4.8 -code Applets.Oscillations.Lissajous.LissajousApplet.class -codebase codebase="../../../" 
WARNING: CURRENTLY GAPPLETVIEWER RUNS WITH NOSECURITY MANAGER.
THIS MEANS THAT APPLETS YOU LOAD CAN DO ANYTHING A JAVA APPLICATION
THAT YOU DOWNLOAD AND RUN CAN DO.  BE *VERY* CAREFUL WHICH APPLETS YOU RUN.
DO NOT USE GAPPLETVIEWER ON YOUR SYSTEM IF YOUR SYSTEM STORES IMPORTANTDATA.
THIS DATA CAN BE DESTROYED OR STOLEN IF YOU LOAD A MALICIOUS APPLET.

[press 'c' or 'C' to continue or anything else to quit]
c
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Applets.Oscillations.Lissajous.LissajousApplet not found in gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.AppletClassLoader{urls=[file:/home/null,file:/home/], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.AppletClassLoader.findClass(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.Main.createApplet(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.StandaloneAppletWindow.<init>(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.StandaloneAppletViewer.createWindows(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.StandaloneAppletViewer.<init>(libgcj-tools.so.14)
   at gnu.classpath.tools.appletviewer.Main.main(libgcj-tools.so.14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the fully qualified classname

```
gappletviewer-4.8 -code Applets.Oscillations.Lissajous.LissajousApplet.class -codebase codebase="http://www.surendranath.org/"
```

Read: [gappletviewer Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gappletviewer-4.2.1.html)

Comment: Thanks, but your last edit suggest that it will not be possible to run it offline. However it also fails: `java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol handler not found: codebase=http`

Comment: Did you try with plain `appletviewer`?

Comment: I tried the same with: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/bin/appletviewer` I am not sure if this is the appletviewer you which you mean. Did it work for you **offline**?

Comment: works perfectly - `appletviewer http://www.surendranath.org/Applets/Oscillations/Lissajous/Lissajous.html`

Comment: Your last command results in an empty applet window for me, both for `gappletviewer-4.8` and the `appletviewer` cited in my comment above. Nevertheless this would be online. But I am looking for a way to run this applet offline.

Comment: In that case why not download the classes directly and use the applet tag from the page on your local machine?

Comment: I tried this already. I will post a minimal html snipped of what I tried.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52529/discussion-between-reimeus-and-julia)